# Override default laravel mail event class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am trying to use [laravel mail events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail#events)  to trigger sent emails , i registed my event in **EventServiceProvider.php** :

```
'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending' => [ 'App\Listeners\CopyEmailIntoSentFolder', ],
```

**CopyEmailIntoSentFolder.php**:

```
class CopyEmailIntoSentFolder
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  MessageSending  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(MessageSending $event)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

is there a way to override **MessageSending.php** class ? i need additional data into my event and **MessageSending.php** [only stores swift_Message](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Mail/Events/MessageSending.html)

Comment: for the love of sanity, start your class names with a captial letter. Properties start with a lowercase letter. And what stops you from firing your own event and listening to it? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events

Comment: @Tschallacka because if i created my own event , i need to change every single controller in my project to add my own event.

Comment: Are you running php 7?

Comment: @Tschallacka 5.6

Comment: I recommend you switch over to php7. Php5.6 is on "security updates only" shortlist and will hit the graveyard at the end of this year https://secure.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: @Tschallacka sure i will do that, but how is that related to my question ?

Comment: Not related but just a heads up that its wise to be along with current versions that are secure.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just plug in a new property on the object.

See it in action: https://ideone.com/PsxiLb

```
class Foo {
    public $message = 'none';

    public function __construct($message) {
        $this->message = $message;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo('hello');
$foo->bar = new Foo('bar');

var_dump($foo);
```

outputs:

```
object(Foo)#1 (2) {
  ["message"]=>
  string(5) "hello"
  ["bar"]=>
  object(Foo)#2 (1) {
    ["message"]=>
    string(3) "bar"
  }
}
```

As you see a property bar was created on the Foo object filled with a new Foo object.

As long as the property doesn't exist yet you can just make a new property on the object and it will get passed along to the other objects it passes to.

You'll have to test if the event object doesn't get reinstated until it arrives at your controllers, but the chances for that happening are slim.